# How to restrict rows in a list inside a document?

Tags: couchdb

I have a document something like:

```
{"name":"Stock levels",
 "content":[
    {"sku":"328143",
     "name":"Battery",
     "stocklevel":"100",
     "warehouse":"london"},
    {"sku":"328143",
     "name":"Battery",
     "stocklevel":"20",
     "warehouse":"manchester"},
    {"sku":"328143",
     "name":"Battery",
     "stocklevel":"30",
     "warehouse":"brighton"}]}
```

Where the list "content" could have quite a lot of rows.

What I want to do is return an internal row count and just one row from the list.
e.g.

```
{"name":"Stock levels",
 "rows" : "2300",
 "content":[
    {"sku":"328143",
     "name":"Battery",
     "stocklevel":"100",
     "warehouse":"london"}]}
```

How might I achieve this in CouchDb? My initial thought is using a list to effectively rebuild the document and inserting the extra rows field and restricting the number of rows return internally, but I am not sure if this is the best approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a view,

the following example allow you to search based on document id
(which is emit as key)

```
function(doc)
{
  if (doc._id == "xxx")
  {
    emit(doc._id, {name:doc.name, rows:doc.content.length, content:doc.content[0]});
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew I was missing something obvious.